# Best Way To Encode and Decode Text PHP

Tags: encode

I'm looking for a method in which I can decode and encode text to be passed in a url.

Not base64

Any others?

Comment: Do you need to encrypt with a password?

Comment: nope, just urls to external sites, and ok I accepted answers :D

Comment: [ROT13](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

- [`rawurlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)
- [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
- [`convert_uuencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php)
- [`quoted_printable_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php)

(and their respective decode routines) or a handful of [other options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php). Without a little more knowledge as to the use case you are trying to solve, though, answers will be lethargic or vague.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has two functions: [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) and [urldecode()](http://php.net/urldecode). Perhaps they are of use to you.

What exactly do you mean decode/encode text to be passed in a URL? If you're looking for a way to pass 'secret' data, using GET parameters is not the right way to do it.

Comment: which was should i do it then? :O POST?